# Power Query Access to the resource is forbidden

Tags: excel, powerquery

I had some power querys on atptour site but now it gives me this error : "exception of type microsoft.mashup.engine.interface.resource access forbiddenexception was thrown"

I tried to clear the connections and do them again but it says "Access to the resource is forbidden."

The site has no login whatsoever so I don't know what is causing this.
Driving nuts here.

Thanks for help.

Regards,